# Django Proxy Field

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to make a Django Proxy Field that has access to another field, but doesn't save anything to the database for it's own value(s), and doesn't have a database column for itself?

The use case for this is we'd like to store values in a `JsonField`, but be able to use the built in validations of Django Fields.  A second benefit of this would being able to add new fields (with validation capability) without affecting the database schema.

The sudo code would probably look something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JsonField

class ProxyInitMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
        # some logic that will hold values if set on the Model
        # but won't create a column or save anything to the
        # database for this Field.
        super(ProxyInitMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ProxyIntegerField(ProxyInitMixin, models.Field):
    pass

class ProxyCharField(ProxyInitMixin, models.Field):
    pass

class MyModel(models.Model):
    proxy_int = ProxyIntegerField()
    proxy_char = ProxyCharField()
    data = JsonField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = {
            'foo': self.proxy_int,
            'bar': self.proxy_char
        }
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why won't Django's Proxy models work for you here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: @Colwin Proxy models are not related to this question

Comment: Why do you want to store values in a `JSONField` if you want to be able to validate or change them through a form? I think it would make more sense to store the values directly on the model. If you still need a `json` you could generate one on the fly using a `@property` function or update the `JSONField` in the `save()`-method.

Comment: @escaped the intention of storing the fields in a `JSONField` is when there's dynamic data based upon multiple tenants for example, and there's a need to validate and store persisted data, but in a dynamic way without having to do a database migration each time.

Comment: if you need to validate your data, you do know the structure. Hence you can store them in a well-defined way. Otherwise, you can only guess how the data has to be validated or do I miss something?

But if I understand you correctly, your requirement was to not do any migration at all, but you are fine with regular updates of the code base to reflect new fields/keys?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The codebase would need knowledge of the data structure in order to use it and validate it even if the data was in a JSONField and there weren't separate defined database columns.

Comment: no you cannot have proxy fields from different model. You can have proxy model. I would suggest you to keep it simple. You should create field in django form for each key/value. And during save, you should validate and save into json.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the field virtual, you need to:

1. Override the `Field.get_attname_column()` method, which must return two-tuple `attname, None` as the value for `attname` and `column`.
2. Set the `private_only` parameter to `True` in the `Field.contribute_to_class()` method.

A proxy field must also have a reference to the concrete field in order to be able to access to it. Here I will use the `concrete_field` parameter.

```
class ProxyMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin class that must be mixed-in with model fields.
    
    The descriptor interface is also implemented in this mixin
    class to keep value getting/setting logic on the Model.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, concrete_field=None, **kwargs):
        self._concrete_field = concrete_field
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def check(self, **kwargs):
        return [
            *super().check(**kwargs),
            *self._check_concrete_field(),
        ]

    def _check_concrete_field(self):
        try:
            self.model._meta.get_field(self._concrete_field)
        except FieldDoesNotExist:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    "The %s concrete field references the "
                    "nonexistent field '%s'." % (self.__class__.__name__, self._concrete_field),
                    obj=self,
                    id='myapp.E001',
                )
            ]
        else:
            return []

    def get_attname_column(self):
        attname, column = super().get_attname_column()
        return attname, None

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=True)
        setattr(cls, name, self)

    @property
    def concrete_field(self):
        """
        Returns the concrete Field instance.
        """
        return self.model._meta.get_field(self._concrete_field)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self._concrete_field is not None:
            kwargs['concrete_field'] = self._concrete_field
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        return getattr(instance, self._concrete_field)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self._concrete_field, value)
```

If you are sure that the concrete field represents a dict-like object, then you can change the logic for getting / setting value. Maybe something like this:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
    if instance is None:
        return self

    data = getattr(instance, self._concrete_field) or {}
    return data.get(self.name, self.get_default())

def __set__(self, instance, value):
    data = getattr(instance, self._concrete_field)
    if data is None:
        setattr(instance, self._concrete_field, {})
        data = getattr(instance, self._concrete_field)
    data[self.name] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

There are proxy models in django, But I am not sure if it has something like proxy fields.

For your use case, you can do as mentioned below:

1. Create a list of fields with each field containing name, type, nullable, etc.
2. Add a function in your model to return actual django rest framework (DRF) field class instance, corresponding to each field type passed to it.
3. Use DRF inbuilt field class validation to validate your field data against specified field type in save().
4. In addition to automatic validation, you will also get automatic type conversion. Eg. If user entered number 1 as text: "1" for a integer field then it will automatically convert it back to integer 1. Same way, it will work for float, Bool, Char, etc

`

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework.fields import IntegerField, FloatField, BooleanField, DateTimeField, CharField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    FIELDS = [{'field_name': 'proxy_int', 'field_type': 'int', 'null_allowed': 'True'},
              {'field_name': 'proxy_char', 'field_type': 'string', 'null_allowed': 'True'}]

    data = JsonField()

    def field_type(self, field):

        if field.field_type == 'int':
            return IntegerField()
        elif field.field_type == 'float':
            return FloatField()
        elif field.field_type == 'bool':
            return BooleanField()
        elif field.field_type == 'date':
            return DateTimeField()
        elif self.value_type == 'string':
            return CharField()
        return CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = kwargs.get('data', {})
        new_data = {}

        for (field in FIELDS)

            field_name = field['field_name']
            field_type = field['field_type']
            field_value = data.get(field_name, None)

            validated_value = self.field_type(field_type).run_validation(field_value)

            new_data[field_name] = validated_value

        kwargs['data'] = new_data
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`
```

You may try and figure out django's field classes (Instead of DRF) and use them for validation, if required.

You can inherit this new MyModel class to achieve similar capability in other models and to reuse code.